# Hitting time of a diffusion process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stopping-times, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider a diffusion process (SDE)

$
dX(t) = \mu (X(t)) dt + \sigma(X(t)) dW(t), X(0) = x.
$

I am interested in a first hitting time of this process to a point $y < x$, more particularly I wonder if there are any explicit formulas for the expectation of the hitting time $\mathbb{E}[\tau]$, where $\tau = \inf \{t\geq 0: X(t) \leq y\}.$ I would assume that the answer should use scale function or speed measure, but I cannot write the expectation explicitly and surpisingly I almost cannot find anything related in classical books. There are some related expressions in Karatzas and Shreeve BMSC (see Chapter 5.5, in particular 5.5.C), but they don't provide a satisfying answer when $X(t)$ is defined on the whole real line.

I will be grateful for the answer or any references where I can find related questions.

Comment: If you know the exact formula of$\mu(x)$ and $\sigma(x)$, perhaps it is possible to find the expectation of the hitting time.

Comment: Otherwise, I don’t think there existes general solution for this generic equation

Comment: @NN2, thanks for your comment! Unfortunately, I don't have exact formulas, but rather some properties, but I want to get some closed-form expression in a general form. In BMSC p344 (5.59) gives some kind if this expression with the use of a scale function and a speed measure, but it is not enough for me.

Comment: Could you post the page 344?

Comment: @NN2 I am not sure whether I am allowed to post screenshots from books here, but you can find the book here: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0949-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they mention,  in Shreve-Karatzas 5.5c, they work on the general setting that *includes* the real line since they allow $\ell=-\infty$ and $r=+\infty$.
So the answer is exactly the one you mentioned at 5.59 in Shreve-Karatzas 5.5c. We simply take $a=y$ $b=+\infty$, then

$$E_{x}[T_{y,\infty}]=M_{y,+\infty}(x),$$

for

[image]

scale function $p$, and speed measure $m$ which are in terms of $\mu,\sigma$.